# Match library does not install in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new, I'm learning python, I tried to install the match library with "pip install match" but it generates an error in the installation and I don't know how to solve it, please help....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz9i8.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: I just opened an [issue](https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/match/issues/24) on the package's repository. As I wrote there, I found no errors installing directly from the repository: `pip install git+https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/match.git@v0.3.1`.

Comment: The package maintainer has fixed the problem; try `pip install match` now.

Comment: if I could install the library but it does not work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don’t post images.

Secondly, the error says it’s a problem with the package. So the fault is on the maintainer/owner. You can contact them to fix it.